# Google GCP Filtering on the source IP ports?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Microsoft Azure has security groups, which allow filtering on the source IP ports.  Does Google’s GCP have the same feature, to filter on the source IP ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Google Cloud security groups do not support specifying the source port number, only the target (destination) port number.

There is no option in any SDK CLI command to specify the source port. The REST APIs do not support source ports.

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) has the following quote:

> GCP firewall rules use port information to reference the destination
>   port of a packet, not its source port: